# Coverage for desktop application in Ruby

Tags: ruby, code-coverage, desktop-application

I am writing a simple desktop application in Ruby. For testing my choice is minitest.
Now I want to measure test-coverage. In case of Ruby on Rails you can use Simplecov (https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov).
Can it be used with desktop app? If so, how?
(I am newbe in Ruby).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs do seem to be written with a bias towards Rails apps, but I don't see anything in there that should prevent you from being able to use Simplecov with any Ruby application, GUI or otherwise. I've used Simplecov for command line apps in the past.

And using minitest should not give you any problems either, based on the section titled ["Use it with any framework"](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov#use-it-with-any-framework).

Comment: Well... unfortunately I can't figure out how to.
In rails app I simply put "require 'simplecov'", "SimpleCov.start 'rails'" in test_helper.rb, what to do if I don't have test_helper around. Sorry, I'm new to Ruby, so far no luck figuring out

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood that. You should be able to create a test_helper.rb file and require it from each of your test files.